# Is Tri-Ply an acceptable underlayment for shingles?

Tags: roofing, underlayment, shingles

My handyman wants to use GAF brand TriPly underneath the new shingles he's installing for the roof repair project. It's a small area and we had half a roll left over from the shed roofing project. Is that OK or do we need regular old roofing felt tar paper?

Answer (score 0):

If GAF markets TriPly as a shingle underlayment, it's hard to imagine that it wouldn't be suitable as an underlayment for any other brand of shingle. After all "regular old roofing felt" is marketed for *all* brands of shingles...

Of course, if you're really paranoid about it, check the label and installation instructions for the brand of shingles you're using on the roof to make sure that it's acceptable for their warranty conditions. Otherwise OwensCorning (for example) might decide to argue that the underlayment is the reason the shingles failed. Of course, if you're just doing a repair, you're probably not going to try to claim a warranty issue on the small patch...

As an anecdote, I just discovered that when my house addition was roofed, they did *not* use regular tar paper as an underlayment. It was something with greyish-white on one side and black on the other. Not certain what was used. I'm sure it'll be just fine.